# Docker postgres database not creating user

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11.3 AS postgres

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Which I am trying to use to launch a database on localhost. The init.sql file has some basic info to configure my db:

```
CREATE USER username;
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test_db TO username;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
(
  event_id uuid NOT NULL,
  length int,
  event_ts timestamp(6) without time zone
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2
(
  event_id uuid NOT NULL,
  value character varying,
  event_ts timestamp(6) without time zone
);
```

When I build the image using `docker build -t dev_db .` it successfully builds. When I then run it with `docker run <image id>` it again appears to successfully run. But when I try to connect to it with psql I get the error:

```
FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

I'm pretty new to docker, could someone point out where I'm going wrong?